# How can columns be fitted?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

I am creating an excel sheet using C#.net with the NetOffice.ExcelApi. I want to autofit the columns A to G with the following code:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
xlWorkSheet.Columns["A:G"].AutoFit();
```

I've also tried this code:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

The result is still that the columns are not fitted.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add the row indexes too, I guess.

I'm using `Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

And this works ok:

```
Excel.Range myRange= xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:G10");
myRange.AutoFit();
```

Maybe there is something like range in NetOffice.ExcelApi too. :|

Btw is there a reason why you don't use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? As the tags say you are writing a windows forms application so there shouldn't be any problem. I think there is more documentation for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

**Update:** I found something in documentation that should help you: http://netoffice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Excel_Example02

```
   // setup rows and columns 
   workSheet.Columns[1].AutoFit(); 
   workSheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth = 25; 
   workSheet.Columns[3].ColumnWidth = 25; 
   workSheet.Columns[4].ColumnWidth = 25; 
   workSheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 25; 
   workSheet.Rows[9].RowHeight = 25;
```

You might want to do something like:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFit();
```

or if it really needs the row index:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:G20").AutoFit();
```

or you can just set all the Columns one by one:

```
xlWorkSheet.Columns[1].AutoFit(); 
xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].AutoFit();
```

I hope something works out for you :).
But it's weird that your `xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();` doesn't work. You should maybe check if the problem isn't in your sheet.

Comment: Probably the solution would have worked with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. But with the NetOffice.ExcelApi it doesn't.

The former programmer of the application where I'm working on has chosen for the NetOffice package. I replaced him at my current position when he left.

Comment: @Nic I updated the answer, that link/code should help you I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I realized that I use the code `myRange.Columns.AutoFit();`  before the text written on excel by the codes.

Please, take a look at this situation.